# Uploading Excel file to database - Office 2013

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I usually upload excel file with data successfully on my database(SQL Server). However we updated our Office to 2013 and I am unable to upload this file. I am very green in programming and any help would be greatly appreciated. Please find my code below.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName)
```

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the error you were receiving; however, I believe this is probably your issue. Follow this link and go to the bottom comment, should shed some light on how to fix your registry to point to the correct .dll file.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-customize/what-is-the-ace-oledb-connection-string-for-excel/bf454873-7e80-4711-94cd-07265d93c434